# Trouble installing Jack on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, jack

Having trouble installing Jack (http://jackaudio.org/downloads/) on Ubuntu 16.04. Main source of error seems to be from the line:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the package name in apt did not match jack1 or jack2 as I would have thought from the downloads page (http://jackaudio.org/downloads/). The actual package names are jackd, jackd1 and jackd2. (Carefull, the package 'jack' seems to be totally unrelated). After attempting to install jackd, I would receive several errors, but they all seemed to arise from this line:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

I found some similar threads troubleshooting various packages with jackd dependencies and happened to find that I had the wrong version of python set as my default. The installation apparently requires python 2.7 or some other 2.* version (untested), but was not telling me that directly in the error messages I received. I had my default python environment set to 3.5 and after changing this to my 2.7 environment, the jackd package installed without error.

After installing any relevant python versions, I changed my python environment using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

From my understanding, you could also use virtualenvs (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)